# How to know if the `onBlur` of a `TextInput` was called because the "enter" key was pressed?

Tags: react-native

In a `TextInput` component with an `onBlur` handler (and with the default `false` `multiline`), when pressing "Enter" the `onBlur` handler is called.

Is there a way for the handler to distinguish between the blurring caused by the "Enter" and any other event?

Comment: You mean the return key in the cell phone text?

Comment: Is there a reason to be distinguished?

Comment: Yes, I mean the "return key" in the cell phone keyboard. And yes, there is a reason, I want certain behavior whenever the input is blurred, except it that was caused by pressing that key.

Answer (score 0):

onSubmitEditing prop might help you

```
<TextInput style={[styles.textInput]}
  placeholder='...'
  placeholderTextColor='#bbb'
  onChange={(event) => {
    this.searchChange(event.nativeEvent.text)
  }}
  returnKeyType='search'
  autoFocus={true}
  value={ this.props.searchName }
  selectionColor={colors.orangeColor}
  onSubmitEditing={this.searchSubmit}
  clearButtonMode="while-editing"
/>
```

Comment: Invalid if multiline={true} is specified.

Comment: He's using a multiline.

Comment: If the blurOnSubmit is set to true, although the onSubmitEditing would be called instead of inserting a new line. Please check

Comment: I didn't know about `blurOnSubmit`. As I said in my original message, I'm using the "default `false` `multiline`", so I only had to add `blurOnSubmit={false}` to get the actual desired behavior (i.e. avoid triggering of the blur handler when "enter" is pressed).

Comment: Try using blurOnSubmit={true} in your existing code